# How to get logged in user info in Office app code

Tags: office-js

I need help in How to get logged in user in office app code. It's a office JSOM (JavaScript Object Model) Api that we use to get information from MS Office product like to read content of MS Word document in which I am using my app to save this content into somewhere for example in SharePoint Document Library as a word document file. 
So I need to know the current user's information like logged in id etc so I can identify who saved this document into SharePoint.
Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Look forward to any response on this?

Comment: Hi All, Any inputs on this question

Comment: digging into OM, could not find any method do get this....

Answer (score 3):

While there is currently no Office JS API to get the current logged-in user, you could always use [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to authenticate the user and then make CORS calls to SharePoint as shown in [this blog](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/adal-js-cors-with-o365-apis-files-sharepoint).

Also, feel free to request such an API on the [Office Extensibility Platform's UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/83526-office-js).

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT